Is it possible to use react infinite scroll components for real time updates?
I am using this component here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component as an instagram/twitter/facebook clone
However, I am looking to get my posts in real time, similar to a chat app. Is it possible to convert infinite scroll components into real time updates? If not are there any react components for this purpose?
